# Using OpenCV Mat as an Array: VB vs C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, opencv, emgucv, mat

I'm using VS2015, EmguCV 3 and VB, and am trying to translate some C++ code.

**C++**

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(bw, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
{...}
```

I'm trying to use some object orientation code given in full [here](https://robospace.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/object-orientation-principal-component-analysis-opencv/). Basically the code is going to tell me the angle at which an object is oriented in an image. Unfortunately it is C++ code and VB developers' brains can explode at the sight of some C++ syntax. Any help avoiding the need to clean my screen again would be welcome. The explosive material was `vector<vector<point> > contours;` in this particular case, and my question is about how to translate it.

I got this far:

**VB**

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
...
contours = New Mat
hierarchy = New Mat
CvInvoke.FindContours(m, contours, hierarchy, CvEnum.RetrType.List, CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxNone)
```

I'm using EmguCV 3. This claims that `FindContours` takes `image As IInputOutputArray, contours As IOutputArray, hierarchy As IOutputArray`. So I figured I could provide three Mats. m is defined earlier has been successfully processed (e.g. with Threshold) so I'm happy with m. contours and hierarchy on the other hand may be problematic. When I run the code, I get an unhandled exception:

> [Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: OpenCV: (_contours.kind() == _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_VECTOR || _contours.kind() == _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_MAT || _contours.kind() == _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_UMAT)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W7wy.png)

This seems to suggest I've passed the wrong types to OpenCV although I would have expected Emgu to handle that. But I have no clue. Any help?

Comment: It seems that a C++ `<` in this context roughly translates as `(` in VB, whilst a `vector` is roughly speaking an array. But more pertinently it turns out that Emgu implements a type called `VectorOfVectorOfPoint`, which I'm now experimenting with. With hierarchy as `VectorOfVectorOfPoint` instead of `Mat`, my code now at least runs without faulting so that's progress! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [**Documentation**](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/cb24a129-d9ce-57f3-19ad-0eaa27a77317.htm) and under the VB section:

> "*contours Type: Emgu.CV.IOutputArray -> Detected contours. **Each contour
>   is stored as a vector of points**."*

Therefore, instead of sending a single `MAT` as your `contours`, you should be sending a container of vectors of points.

See here [**The Equivalent of C++ Vectors for VB.Net**](https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/626121-vectors-vb-net).

Comment: Ah... a container of vectors of points! Yes, of course 8-/ ! OK, I will try to find out what one of those is. Many thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Yeah, obviously. Glad we were able to help :) ;)

Comment: So, it turns out Emgu provides a class called `VectorOfVectorOfPoints` expressly for this purpose. I now have working code! Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Here you go :) Good job.